# How to query contacts from exchange server using LIKE operator?

Tags: java

I want to query contacts from exchange server by using LIKE operator, i am using 
**SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring** & passing text as **LIKE Sa%** but it's not returning any data. when i passing **Sa%** it's taking whole condition as a string.

```
if (comparisonOperation.equalsIgnoreCase("like")) {
    SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(filterData.getFieldType(), filterData.getFieldValue().toString(), ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase);

    ilterCollection.add(filter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are nothing like `LIKE Sa%` in java, instead you can use Mactches with a regex for example you can replace `Sa%` with `Sa(.*?)` for example :

```
String str = "Samsung";
if(str.matches("Sa(.*?)")){
    System.out.println("yes");
}
```